# Unique GTM account for multiple landing pages with diferent UA codes

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I would like to know if there is a way to achieve that a GTM account with 4 tags firing events can be used in many landings pages with diferent UA codes.

Currently each tag is ready to fire an event to a specific UA account... but can't see if there is a way generalize to a UA-XXXXXXX-{{dinamic-ID}}

*Here is an explanation of my goal:*

[image]

Comment: Why would you want to use multiple GA? Just use one GA with Domain Linker option enabled.

Comment: @SimonHayter I didn't know there was something like this. I inherited what was already done.

Still, that allows me to continue having separate data from each web?

Comment: Yes, you can view it as a 'whole' or individually, people use it for sub domains and other domains if they are somehow linked... otherwise they would never see the bigger picture.

Comment: [Set up cross-domain tracking (analytics.js)](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1034342?hl=en) using: `ga('linker:autoLink', ['exampleA.com', 'exampleB.com'] );`

Answer (score 1):

Domain Linker is a preferred method.  However, to consider the options: incorporating multiple landing pages into your conversion tracker and getting solid analytics can be tricky. You could multiple GTM accounts with tag(s) and code(s) assigned to different landing pages. This would seem excessive overhead to me and I wonder if they would not "get in each other's way" in terms of directing traffic and seeing which area is preferred by visitors.  And I am not sure what the precise SEO impact would be with this.